# take screenshot of a page area and put it on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, screenshot

Good evening guys.

I'm working on a project in which i have an image upload canvas with draggable elements to put it over the uploaded image.

Is kinda messy right now, as the elements are absolute positioned to a 800px resolution. [Here is the demo.](http://drconstrucciones.net/demo/santababy/subetufoto6.html)

What i need now is to have a button that takes an screenshot of the canvas region, and then takes this screenshot to another canvas in another page.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

1) First convert the canvas to to data url like this :

`var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();`

2) Pass this value to next page.

3) Then load that url :

```
 function loadCanvas(dataURL) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // load image from data url
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        };

        imageObj.src = dataURL;
   }
```

For more details refer :

Converting Data Url: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-load-image-data-url/

Loading Data Url : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-load-image-data-url/